# how to use authentication of spring 3.0 with JSF

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, authentication, annotations

i have develop project on JSF 2-0+spring 3.0 +hibernate ,all annotation based but now i want to add log in header so what should i do to access authentication through spring 3.0 throughout whole project.i have not use authentication through spring ever please help me and guide me stepwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below link would help you to configure.

[JSF-Spring security Integration](http://ocpsoft.org/java/acegi-spring-security-jsf-login-page/)

Comment: thanks that is the one way i was searching.its stepwise.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use spring security by adding DelegatingFilterProxy to deployment descriptor and configure spring security in application context check below video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yWttTlPkqYU